# Next-Intl not working for nested routes in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, middleware, next.js13, app-router, next-intl

I am using `next-intl` for internationalization. I have followed the installation instructions [here](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router). This works as expected on the index/home page, however, when I try to navigate to /register it ignores the locale and thus returns `not-found.jsx`

I am using `<Link href={"/register"}>` to navigate.

### Folder structure

```
src
|-- app
|   |-- [locale]
|       |-- (public)
|           |-- layout.jsx
|           |-- page.jsx
|           |-- not-found.jsx
|           |-- register
|               |-- page.jsx
|-- middleware.js
|-- i18n.js
```

### middleware.js

```
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";

export default createMiddleware({
  locales: ["en", "ka", "ru"],
  defaultLocale: "en",
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/(en|ka|ru)/:path*"],
};
```

### i18n.js

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { getRequestConfig } from "next-intl/server";

const locales = ["en", "ka", "ru"];

export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => {
  if (!locales.includes(locale)) notFound();

  return {
    messages: (await import(`../messages/${locale}.json`)).default,
  };
});
```